# Is this a valid XPath expression?

Tags: xpath, xml-libxml

Is this xpath a valid XPath expression? (It does what it should ).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings; use 5.012;
use XML::LibXML;

my $string =<<EOS;
<result>
    <cd>
    <artists>
        <artist class="1">Pumkinsingers</artist>
        <artist class="2">Max and Moritz</artist>
    </artists>
    <title>Hello, Hello</title>
    </cd>
    <cd>
    <artists>
        <artist class="3">Green Trees</artist>
        <artist class="4">The Leons</artist>
    </artists>
    <title>The Shield</title>
    </cd>
</result>
EOS
#/
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->load_xml( string => $string );
my $root = $doc->documentElement;

my $xpath = '/result/cd[artists[artist[@class="2"]]]/title';

my @nodes = $root->findnodes( $xpath );
for my $node ( @nodes ) {
    say $node->textContent;
}
```

Comment: With Perl 5.012, you don't need to turn on strict yourself. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep. That's a valid XPath expression.

It could be a little simplier if you wrote it as:

```
/result/cd[artists/artist[@class="2"]]/title
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use any expression inside a predicate, which means you can nest them.

#### References

- [w3c.org/XPath 2.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/)

  - [Basics](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-basics) - "In general, the operands of an expression are other expressions. XPath allows expressions to be nested with full generality"
  - [Predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-predicates) - `Predicate ::= "[" Expr "]"`
- [xml.com Top Ten Tips to Using XPath and XPointer](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/08/14/xpath_tips.html)

  - "Keep an open mind about predicates: nested, 'compound,' and so on."